# How to convert vector [1 2 3 :a :b :c :A :B :C] to [ {:index 1 :lower :a :upper :A} {:index 2 :lower :b :upper :B} {:index 3 :lower :c :upper :C} ]?

Tags: clojure

I want to know how to convert

```
vector [1 2 3 :a :b :c :A :B :C]
```

to

```
[ {:index 1 :lower :a :upper :A} {:index 2 :lower :b :upper :B} {:index 3 :lower :c :upper :C}  ]  ?
```

the vector may be [1 2 3 4 :a :b :c :d :A :B :C :D]

or if there is not an easy way,is there a way to convert

```
[{:index 1} {:index 2} {:index 3}]  [{:lower :a} {:lower :b} {:lower :c}]   [{:upper :A} {:upper :B} {:upper :C}]
```

to

```
[{:index 1 :lower :a :upper :A} {:index 2 :lower :b :upper :B} {:index 3 :lower :c :upper :C}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried. The problem seems a little contrived - where is this vector coming from? Perhaps (partition (/ (count v) 3) v) might be a good start...

Comment: something like that would do the trick: `(apply map (comp (partial zipmap [:index :lower :upper]) vector) (partition 3 data))` . But ok, your input structure seems to be inappropriate for this task. i would probably start with rearranging the data model

Comment: @leetwinski the `3` should be `(/ (count data) 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in general, when faced with a problem like this, I would go upstream and fix the input format. A vector that is a concatenation of arbitrary parts doesn't make any sense. For the sake of an answer, let us assume this isn't possible.

First we define a helper function to create the result maps:

```
(defn make-result [i l u]
    {:index i :lower l :upper u})
```

Then we just need to map this function over the three subsequences:

```
(defn input->output [i]
    (apply map make-result (partition (/ (count i) 3) i)))
```

We need to use apply as we generate a sequence of subsequences that we want to use as the parameters for map (recall that the function arity should match the number of sequences you pass to map - which conveniently our helper does).

This will work for both of the vectors given above.

```
(input->output [1 2 3 :a :b :c :A :B :C])
({:index 1, :lower :a, :upper :A} {:index 2, :lower :b, :upper :B} {:index 3, :lower :c, :upper :C})
(input->output [1 2 3 4 :a :b :c :d :A :B :C :D])
({:index 1, :lower :a, :upper :A} {:index 2, :lower :b, :upper :B} {:index 3, :lower :c, :upper :C} {:index 4, :lower :d, :upper :D})
```

Behaviour if the vector is in a different format may surprise or disappoint - perhaps some input validation is in order.

Answer (score 1):

```clj
(let [ks [:index :lower :upper]
      xs [1 2 3 :a :b :c :A :B :C]]
  (->> xs
       (partition (/ (count xs) (count ks)))
       (apply map vector)
       (mapv zipmap (repeat ks))))
```

How it works:

We first `partition` the vector by `count`:

`(partition (/ (count xs) (count ks)) xs)=> ((1 2 3) (:a :b :c) (:A :B :C))`

Then transpose the matrix:

`(apply map vector *1)=> ([1 :a :A] [2 :b :B] [3 :c :C])`

Finally `zipmap` with the provided keys for each row:

`(mapv zipmap (repeat ks) *1)=> [{:index 1, :lower :a, :upper :A} {:index 2, :lower :b, :upper :B} {:index 3, :lower :c, :upper :C}]`

Comment: I like it. A simpler last line is `(mapv (partial zipmap ks))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide a list of the key-values, like the following (formatted to improve readability):

```
(def items [[{:index 1}  {:index 2}  {:index 3}]
            [{:lower :a} {:lower :b} {:lower :c}]
            [{:upper :A} {:upper :B} {:upper :C}]])
```

then you can use the following:

```
(apply map merge items)
;; returns ({:index 1, :lower :a, :upper :A} {:index 2, :lower :b, :upper :B} {:index 3, :lower :c, :upper :C})
```

This works by using the `map` function to `merge` the individual hash-maps in the 3 collections. First, the first elements of each collection are merged together, resulting in the element `{:index 1, :lower :a, :upper :A}`, then the second elements of each collection are merged, and so on.

Since the arguments to `map merge` are a collection, you need to use `apply` to provide the arguments to `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a clojure expert but maybe this helps:

```
; your data
(def x [1 2 3 :a :b :c :A :B :C])

; resolve symbols and numbers to strings
(def xa (map (fn [e] (if (keyword? e) (name e) (str e))) x))


; split into three sequences and zip this lists together
(let [xan (filter (fn [e] (not (empty? (re-matches #"[0-9]" e)))) xa)
     xaa (filter (fn [e] (not (empty? (re-matches #"[a-z]" e)))) xa)
     xaA (filter (fn [e] (not (empty? (re-matches #"[A-Z]" e)))) xa)]
     (map-indexed (fn [i e] {:index e :lower (nth xaa i) :upper (nth xaA i)}) xan ))
```

You just build three sequences and iterate over any of them and use the index to access the corresponding elements from the other.